# How can i get particular data from JSON response?

Tags: objective-c

How can i get particular data from JSON response? Here below response from my server. ineed to get A, B, C then need to get A.data values.

```
{
       response   =     (
                  {
              A =             (
                                {
                    data = "2014-05-21";            
                    name = "percent";               

                    );
                }
            );
            B =             (
                                {
                    data = "2014-05-23";            
                    name = "short";                  

                    );
                },
                                {
                    data = "2014-05-23";             
                    name = "mam";                    
                    );
                },
                                {
                    data = "2014-05-23";             
                    name = "sinh";                
                    );
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? Is something wrong with working with [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html)?  . Just a side note: Always double check using isKindOfClass what type of object you receive from the deserializer.

It could look like this:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization 
    JSONObjectWithData:data 
    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
    error: &e];
if ([responseDict isKindOfClass[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *abcDict = [responseDict objectForKey:@"response"];
    if (abcDict isKindOfClass [NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dataSetDict = [abcDict objectForKey:@"A"];
        if ([dataSetDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class] {
            // Here it might get difficult. In case of the key A you get a dictionary but 
            // the key B will return an array of dictionaries. And even the data fields 
            // may vary. In your example you will have strings only but you better double check.
        }

    }
}
```

And check for the error e, which I didn't. 
And deal with the case that you many not receive what you expected to receive. So add else statements and deal with the issue, throw and catch an exception or so.

Comment: I need to get "A" "B" ,... objects.

Comment: NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"response"];
    // NSLog(@"keys %d",latestLoans.count);
    NSDictionary *d1 = latestLoans.firstObject;
    NSEnumerator *enum1 = d1.keyEnumerator;
    
    for(int i=0;i<d1.count;i++){
    
        NSLog(@"Company:%@",enum1.nextObject);
    
    }